# Getting MAMP Pro Apache to Listen on Multiple TCP Ports

Tags: apache, apache2, mamp

I'm running MAMP Pro (Currently 3.5).

I would like to be able to run Apache's standard (non-SSL) TCP on multiple ports (80 and 8080) for testing.

It doesn't seem to let me do this. Adding a new TCP port to the httpd.conf doesn't do it, so I guess that MAMP Pro ignores that and replaces it with 80.

Any clues as to how I do this?

EDIT: I do have a support ticket open on this, but it can take them a while to get back, and I'm an impatient S.O.B., as I'm running on the assumption that I am [not] doing something right/wrong, and the answer is in front of my nose.

Comment: Just to be clear, you've specified multiple `Listen` ports as specified here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html and you've completely stopped and started Apache again? What OS are you running MAMP on?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.11.3 (Latest El Capitan). MAMP is 3.5 (Latest). Yes, I tried editing the httpd.conf in their "conf" directory, as well as the one in the "MAMP Templates" directory at user root. I used the MAMP start and stop to restart (not reload).

Comment: Oh, also, just to be clear: The documented Apache binding is what I want, with both ports 80 and 8080 running. I now have to specify one or the other (or set up hosts with one or the other). I'd like to have one host, two ports. It's a convenience thing; not a showstopper, but it makes a huge difference. That's what I use for my hosted test server (also dual ports for SSL).

Comment: Oh, I should probably mention how I workaround this now. I have additional hosts defined (server-alt.localhost, etc.) that specify 8080. The problem is that some Web apps require a fixed server name, which gets pooched when you have multiple hosts. In these cases, I need to change the port in the host, then restart. It's a mild PItA.

Comment: I think you need to specify additional hosts/vhosts otherwise Apache doesn't know where to send requests coming on different ports to. From the above link:  `This is often combined with the Virtual Host feature, which determines how httpd responds to different IP addresses, hostnames and ports.`  I think you've got an answer here, which you can add below and accept, and if you here back differently from the developers of MAMP, then you can edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer I got from Appsolute. Basically "Oh, you can't get there from here." It's by no means a showstopper. It just means that I need to restart the server for testing. Since unusual ports are a bit of an edge case for me, it's not a regular test (but is becoming more popular, these days -especially with SSL). I put in a feature request with them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conferring with Appsolute (the makers of MAMP), they informed me that I can't currently do this. They basically suggested the same thing I tried above (which didn't work); which was to edit the template file.

It's not a showstopper, and I did put in a feature request to them, so maybe this will show up in future releases.